# Terminate Observable by timeout

Tags: scala, rx-java, rx-scala

I'm trying to limit life of observable by timeout:

```
def doLongOperation() = {
   Thread.sleep(duration)
   "OK"
}

def firstStep = Observable.create(
  (observer: Observer[String]) => {
    observer.onNext(doLongOperation())
    observer.onCompleted()
    Subscription()
  }
)

firstStep
  .timeout(1 second)
  .subscribe(
    item => println(item),
    throwable => throw throwable,
    () => println("complete")
  )
```

I would like to distinguish between following results:

1. Observable finished by timeout, no result obtained
2. Exception thrown during execution
3. Execution finished successfully, return value

I can process cases 2 and 3 with no problem in partials onNext and onError, but how do I detect if observable finished by timeout?

One more thing: I've never get into block onComplete, though there is a call to obeserver.onCompleted() in my code. Why?

Comment: Operator `timeout` will emit a TimeoutException on the onError lane.

Comment: @akarnokd, What's wrong with my code then? Since I don't get any exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a timeout happens, that `TimeoutException` is emitted on the computation thread where a `throw throwable` is ends up being ignored and your main thread won't and can't see it. You can add `toBlocking` after the timeout so any exception will end up on the same thread:

```
firstStep
  .timeout(1 second)
  .toBlocking()
  .subscribe(
    item => println(item),
    throwable => println(throwable),
    () => println("complete")
```

)

Comment: You are absolutely right, exception get thrown. The problem was in another place: I was using wrong dependencies: "com.netflix.rxjava" instead of "io.reactivex".

Answer (score 0):

TimeoutException gets thrown indeed. The problem was caused by using wrong libraries. I had "com.netflix.rxjava" in my dependencies, instead of "io.reactivex"